# Infer TypeScript Props in React component connected to Redux?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Im used to connecting React componts to Redux like this:

In index.js:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { doThing } from "store/actions";
import Component from "./component";

const mapState = (state) => {
  const { foo } = state;
  return {
    foo
  };
};

const mapDispatch = {
  doThing,
};

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Component);
```

In component.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Component = ({foo, doThing}) => {
    return (
        // stuff
    )
}
```

This has worked great but now I've moved over to TypeScript:

In index.tsx:

```
import { stateType } from "types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { doThing } from "store/actions";
import Component from "./component";

const mapState = (state: stateType) => {
  const { foo } = state;
  return {
    foo
  };
};

const mapDispatch = {
  doThing,
};

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(Component);
```

In component.tsx

```
import { doThingArgTypes } from "types";
import React from 'react';

type Props = {
  foo: string;
  doThing: (arg0: doThingArgTypes) => void;
};


const Component: React.FC<Props> = ({foo, doThing}) => {
    return (
        // stuff
    )
}
```

The code above works but it's annoying having to type out `Props` every time given that in some situations TypeScript can infer types. Also if I import a prop and dont use it I dont get any errors. Is there a smarter way to add types?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: No, I don't think it can be done: https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#redux-connected-components

Comment: Yeahh I know. I have read this too. I just install and integrate `typesafe-actions` into all my projects that uses TS/React/Redux to solve all these issues..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is another way to go around it. You have to provide the interfaces/type aliases for your React components, otherwise, the TypeScript compiler will throw an error stating that is similar to this: `Property “XXX” does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes`.

Sure, you can always take the easy way out and type your components as `any`, but that would defeat the one of the reasons of using TypeScript, as you will lose typechecking capabilities.

If you are working with connected components with `Redux` and other middlewares such as `redux-observable`, you may choose to use this package, [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions), which provides a bunch of typesafe utilities.